# Selenium throw no exception in case invalid URL-scheme used

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written two scripts: one using `requests` and the other using `selenium`.

When I execute my first script, I see that it never prints anything as it can't get past this line `res = requests.get(link)` when there is an error and as a result the printing never happens. However, in case of selenium, I get different behavior. I know I supplied an invalid link and still I can see the result what this line `print("Executing: " + driver.current_url)` produces?

How can I stop my selenium script when it hits this line `driver.get(link)` no matter there is an inavid url supplied or no valid response or no url is there at all?

First script (it behaves in the right way):

```
import requests

link = "httppss://www.google.com/search?q=selenium"

res = requests.get(link) #error thrown here just as expected
print("Executing: " + res.url)
```

Second script (it runs smoothly when it sould throw error):

```
from selenium import webdriver

link = "httppss://www.google.com/search?q=selenium"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link) #expected any error to be thrown here
print("Executing: " + driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Selenium sent the URL and the browser successfully complained about it.  What exception were you expecting?

Comment: Why *would* that throw an error? Your browser doesn't just crash out when you try to visit an invalid URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InvalidSchema` is `requests`-specific exception. `requests` supports `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocols only, and `get_adapter` method checks whether URL-schema is in `['HTTP', 'HTTPS']` list. If not `InvalidSchema` exception raised...

Selenium has no such *invalid schema handler*, so (as expected) no exception raised in case you want to get URL with schema like `"httppss"`

You can of course update your `selenium.common.exceptions` module locally, so it will contain

```
class InvalidSchemaException(WebDriverException):
    """Raises if URL-schema is not supported"""
    pass
```

add imports to `webdriver` module:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import (InvalidArgumentException,
                                        WebDriverException, InvalidSchemaException)
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

and modify `get` as

```
def get(self, url):
    """
    Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    """
    schema = urlparse(url).scheme
    if scheme.upper() not in ['HTTP', 'HTTPS']:
        raise InvalidSchemaException('Schema "%s" is not supported' % scheme)
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
```

but it's just a workaround, you might use this approach only if you **really need it**